# How to install mate over existing ubuntu desktop?

Tags: 17.10, mate, gnome-shell

I have an existing ubuntu 17.10 desktop install.

I've heard many great things about this [MATE desktop environment](https://mate-desktop.org/). For most of what I know it should work as a regular shell. How should I install the Ubuntu MATE session?

Comment: `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop` will add it to your system, when you login you can select which you use for that session (mate, gnome ...)

Comment: Please do a proper answer so I can accept it :). Anyway. Is there any know drawback? are there too many depdendencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop`

which will add the Ubuntu-MATE desktop to your system (including all apps that come with the Ubuntu-MATE had you installed it).

At login time, you can select if you want GNOME, MATE for the current session. If you want to switch, logout and you can switch the other DEsktop.

Comment: As for issues - I usually always install standard Ubuntu, then add Xubuntu & Ubuntu-MATE desktops as I'm an old gnome2 user (up to 11.04) and so use gnome apps; but prefer gnome2 type (MATE) feel & XFCE.  Only issue can be larger updates (as you'll get updates for GNOME & MATE but the core is the same so only one there), you'll need more disk space (two DEsktops installed plus two sets of apps). Some DEsktop menus can be large & a little confusing, eg. if you want an editor in MATE - Pluma is most efficient; but gedit still shows... You can waste memory by selecting the wrong one..

Comment: If you have 4Gb or more memory, you can ignore the memory issue (unless you're doing something that requires all you ram). The issue with the wrong apps (eg. if you liked Amorak which is a Qt app) it can't use your system's GTK+ libs, so it causes Qt apps to be loaded too. For modern MATE & GNOME (both GTK+ 3) its not an issue anyway  (this is maybe technical)

Comment: Visually you may find gnome apps don't fit perfectly with your mate desktop (and vice-versa),  but if you're like me you won't care (as long as they work! which they do).  Don't forget to add the `mate-tweak` tool, and explore the switching layouts (maybe wrong term), it's cool.

Comment: 2nd last comment typo - '.. GTK+ libs, so it causes Qt **libs** [not apps] to be loaded too...'